# mon-service ubuntu daemon service start failure

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

I have written a service using mono develop on ubuntu 12.04 LTS with `FileSystemWatcher`. The service is running fine but when I try to run it using script as ubuntu daemon my log file shows that the service is running but `FileSystemWatcher` is not raising events although when I run script by double clicking on it then service runs fine.
Here is my `OnStart` method:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]            
protected override void OnStart (string[] args)
{
    try
    {               
        WriteLog("dir Srvc On Start");
        string d = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher ();
        watcher.Path = d;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = 
            NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName |
            NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);    
        watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler (OnError);    
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        WriteLog("On Startup Exeption: "+ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is my `OnCreated` Methhod:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
private void OnCreated(Object O, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        WriteLog(e.FullPath.ToString() + " " + e.Name.ToString() + " " 
                 + e.ChangeType.ToString());    
        string outputdir = "OutPut";
       string d = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string outdir = Path.Combine(d,outputdir);
        Directory.CreateDirectory (outdir);
        string outputfile = Path.Combine (outdir,e.Name);   
        File.Move(e.FullPath,outputfile);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        WriteLog("On Created Exeption: "+ex.ToString());
    }       
}
```

And my executable script which I put on rc2.d directory:

```
#!/bin/sh    
mono-service -l:/dir/forlock/service.lock  /dir/forsrvc/dirWatchSrvc.exe
```

Also I'm new to ubuntu don't know much about scripting in it.

**updated**

i updated the code but its still not working

Comment: that may not be the actual error, but you are using Path.Combine wrong. Correct usage would be `Path.Combine(dir,towatch,outputdir)`. The point of that method is to *not* use a hardcoded directory seperator and at the same time not having to worry about directory seperators inside the string variables you are trying to join, so that something like `C:\\\\test\\testdfile.exe\\` does not happen.

Comment: thanks Steffen for your reply but this code working when i run the script via double click only problem is that when this script run through os boot sequence then the service is running but the file System watcher events not raised

Comment: or i run it through sudo /etc/init.d/myscript start